What is the maximum possible regression performance of a model on noisy data?
Lets say I am intersted in how fast something decays, so I measure its levels over time. I perform several replicates so I have several measurements at each time point, and then use that data to estismate the decay rate for an exponential decay model $y=e^{-\lambda t}$ giving me an estimate of $\lambda$ and a standard error of that estimate. Now lets say that the standard errors are fairly large compared to the decay rates, so the data is noisey.
Now lets say that I am intersted in working out what affects the decay rate. The data might be (mostly) noisey, but I have tens of thousands of cases.
I divide my data into train, validation and test, and try training a range of models - lasso regression, random forests, gradient boosting trees, I even have a quick try with a CNN. In the test set, what ever I do, the $R^2$ for each of these models is around 0.4.
There are several explainations for this. One is that that there are important variables missing, or that the models are wrong in form or structure. But its also possibly due to the noisiness in the data.
Is there any way to measure the maximum possible performance of a regression model, given a measure of confidence in the data?
This question: Estimating maximum predictive power in noisy data is relevant for classication tasks, but I'm wondering about regression here. Plus I think the real model needs to be known, which it isn't.
It stuck me that it would be difficult for a model to do better than an additional replicate of real data. I wondered if I simulated a new replicate of each of the ten thousand cases (by picking a new lambda randomly from a normal distribution with a standard deviation equal to the standard error of the real data) and then measured the correlation between the ten thousand simulated values and the ten thousand real values, that might give me an upper bound on what I could expect from the model. Doing this gives an $R^2$ of about 0.4! Does this sound reasonable?

Related: (1) (2) (3) (4)
